# Select PHP PDO best way to make

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have a question on how to draw a connection to a select box that is inside a function.

I call this way:

Function MySQL:
mysql.php

```
function conectar() {

try {
    $dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=adm-new", 'root', '');
} catch (PDOException $dbe) {
    echo $dbe->getMessage();
}

    return $dbh;

}

$conn = conectar();
```

Function select:
menu.php

```
function z_menu_todos() {   

    global $conn;

    $z_menu = "SELECT * 
            FROM z_menu 
            ORDER BY posicao ASC";

    return $conn->prepare($z_menu);

}
```

I did not want to call the variable global $conn.
What would be the best way to do?

Comment: Use a class, and store `$conn` as an instance variable.

Comment: Could you show me an example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would create a `DatabaseFactory` class which would serve for creating database connection, like this:

**ConnectionFactory.php**

```
class ConnectionFactory {
    private $_connection;

    public function __construct($dbName, $dbUser, $dbPassword, $dbHost = 'localhost'){
        try {
            $this->_connection = new PDO("mysql:host=$dbHost;dbname=$dbName", $dbUser, $dbPassword);
            $this->_connection->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
        } catch (PDOException $e){
            throw new DatabaseFactoryException('Could not create connection:' . $e->getMessage());
        }
    }

    public function getConnection(){
        return $this->_connection;
    }
}
```

After that I would create `MenuRepository` class which would server for executing queries associated with Menu, like this:

**MenuRepository.php**

```
class MenuRepository {
    private $_connection;

    public function __construct(PDO $connection){
        $this->_connection = $connection;
    }

    public function getMenus(){
        $stmt = $this->_connection->prepare("SELECT * FROM z_menu ORDER BY posicao ASC");
        $stmt->execute();

        return $stmt->fetchAll();
    }
}
```

I would create configuration in separate file, like this:

**config.php**

```
define('DB_NAME', 'adm-new');
define('DB_USER', 'root');
define('DB_PASS', '');
```

After that I would use:

**index.php**

```
require __DIR__ . '/config.php';
require __DIR__ . '/ConnectionFactory.php';
require __DIR__ . '/MenuRepository.php';

$connectionFactory = new ConnectionFactory(DB_NAME, DB_USER, DB_PASS);
$connection = $connectionFactory->getConnection();

$menuRepository = new MenuRepository($connection);
$menus = $menuRepository->getMenus();
```

Comment: @Mourinha make sure you study what the factory pattern is, just copy and pasting will not help you learn anything.

Answer (score -1):

```
class Database
{
    protected $conn;

    public function __construct()
    {
        try {
            $this->conn = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=adm-new", 'root', '');
        } catch (PDOException $dbe) {
            echo $this->conn->getMessage();
        }
    }

    public function z_menu_todos()
    {
        $z_menu = "SELECT * 
            FROM z_menu 
            ORDER BY posicao ASC";

        return $this->conn->prepare($z_menu);
    }
}
```

**Usage**

```
$database = new Database();
$stmt = $database->z_menu_todos();
```

Modify this as you require, this is a very basic example of how to do this, do not just copy and paste it.

Comment: Your `Menu` methods are tightly connected to your `Database` class. It should be separate class.

Comment: as I mentioned in the answer, this is only to demonstrate how to simply wrap a database connection with a class... I'm not going to write a full blown database class for him

Answer (score -1):

In this case, you should avoid using global variables, because you can easily pass the connection to method as method argument, like this:

```
function conectar() {
    try {
        $dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=adm-new", 'root', '');
    } catch (PDOException $dbe) {
        echo $dbe->getMessage();
    }
    return $dbh;
}

$conn = conectar();

function z_menu_todos($conn) {   
    $z_menu = "SELECT *  FROM z_menu ORDER BY posicao ASC";

    return $conn->prepare($z_menu);
}
```

However, it might be a good idea to create a separate class for managing your database connection and other stuff purely related to database and another class for executing SQL queries against your menu table.

Comment: Funny how my answer is similar but got -2

Comment: @meda It is similar, but probably not verbose enough, but honestly, I don't know why you have down votes.